# Why does jQuery not generate an object when I delegate an event to an identifier?

Tags: jquery

My code is a simple "on click":

```
jQuery('.selector').on('click', function(event) {});
```

But `this` as of now is just a dom tree, the element I delegated the event to. Why does jQuery not create an object that I can further use without me having to do:

`let current_object = jQuery(this);`

Which I feel is a loss of time.

Comment: In my experience it does not, did you look at the documentation?

Comment: @maxpelic Ah, snap, I mistyped. My question is rather "why does jQuery choose not to create a jQuery object and instead just returns the dom tree?", I read, of course and tested / dumped to see what's up.

Answer (score 2):

What you refer to as "jQuery object" is essentially a *collection*. It is a collection of DOM elements. Whether or not such a collection consists of just one element or more makes no difference to the fact that it is a collection.

When you attach a click handler to the *collection* (or iterate it,...) the callback is called with exactly *one element* of the collection, which is... a DOM element. It is now not a collection, although you are free to create one from it with `$(this)`. But it makes sense that when the context is about exactly one element, that you get that, and not a collection.

Also, the goal of jQuery is not to replace the standard DOM API. It is supposed to be a helpful layer, without aiming to take the coder away from the core. One can think of features that the DOM API provides, where jQuery offers less functionality. For instance, jQuery is less developed for working with text nodes, and some properties (like `.nodeType`) do not have a direct equivalent in jQuery.

Compare how it works with JavaScript Array objects. They are collections of values, providing lots of interesting methods (like `sort`, `reverse`, `indexOf`, ...). But when you iterate them with `forEach` (or `map`, `find`, ...), the callback will receive the inner value as-is, not wrapped as an Array object. jQuery applies the same principle.

Comment: I see, but if I dump `this` vs `jQuery(this)`, the first one is just a node, where as the second one is an object with methods on it, it's clearly not just a collection, it might be, but every element in that collection would then have access to every method jQuery provided by default, as clearly seen in the dump.

Comment: The collection has methods, but it is a bit strange to say that elements in that collection have access to every method. It is the opposite: these methods access the elements. It's much like an Array object: it provides methods like `includes`, `reverse`, `indexOf`. But when you iterate an Array (like with `forEach`) you get each element as-is, not an element wrapped as Array. It is the same principle with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

That's right - `this` inside a handler refers to the element that triggered the event. If you want to use jQuery methods on it, you'll have to wrap it in `$` to get a jQuery object first.

If you want to avoid having to do that, if you're just trying to set a certain data attribute, feel free to use `.dataset` instead, for example:

```js
jQuery('.selector').on('click', function(event) {
  this.dataset.attribute = 'foo';
});
```

```css
[data-attribute="foo"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">click</div>
```

This behavior is identical to event handlers in vanilla JS: `this` refers to the element that triggered the event, which is in line with the principle of least astonishment:

```js
document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  this.dataset.attribute = 'foo';
});
```

```css
[data-attribute="foo"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">click</div>
```

It would be *possible* to create an `on` function that wraps `this` in jQuery first, though it'd be a bit odd:

```js
const on = (selector, event, handler) => {
  $(selector).on(event, function(...args) {
    handler.apply($(this), args);
  });
};
on('.selector', 'click', function(event) {
  this.attr('data-attribute', 'foo');
});
```

```css
[data-attribute="foo"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">click</div>
```

Comment: Got it, that's what I wanted to ask in reality was asking why does jQuery, by design choices...chose not to give you an object and just the dom tree.

Comment: Because native event listeners are also called with a `this` representing the element the listener was attached to - jQuery is only imitating that behavior. Anything you can do with jQuery operations on a DOM element, you can also do with vanilla DOM operations.

Answer (score 1):

In the event that an event listener can get enough information from the `this` to do its work, if jQuery always automatically gave you a jQuery object, it would be introducing unavoidable overhead.  Instead, jQuery provides the `this` to the event listener, and then it is up to you to decide if the added overhead of instantiating a new jQuery object is necessary.